# PHP Multi XML POST with loop using CURL

Tags: php, xml, post, curl, while-loop

I have multiple `XML_PAYLOAD`'s to post (different xml posts for each while loop).  When I run the loop it will only `POST` the data of the first `$i` loop.  How can I get it to `POST` new data for each `$i` loop?

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < $num) {

...data

define("XML_PAYLOAD", "<?xml stuff and tags?>");
define("XML_POST_URL", "http://theurl");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, XML_POST_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, XML_PAYLOAD);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$i++;
}
```

Comment: It needs to be in there because it needs to have different data it pulls from the loop.

Comment: At first glance, the use of defines would be an issue. You can only define a constant once. So if your payloads are different in each loop, you wouldn't be able to redefine XML_PAYLOAD nor XML_POST_URL, so you would send the same thing $num times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[define](http://php.net/define) defines a constant. It means that it cannot change once it set. You should use variables like that:

```
define("XML_POST_URL", "http://theurl");
$i = 0;
while ($i < $num) {

...data

$xml_payload = "<?xml stuff and tags?>";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, XML_POST_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, XML_PAYLOAD);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$i++;
}
```

Comment: Very simple and easily overlooked by me, thank you this solved it!